# How to prove the identity $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}J_n(x)\,J_{n+m}(x) = 0$ using the Bessel generating function?

Tags: generating-functions, bessel-functions

I need some help proving the following identity:

$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}J_n(x)\,J_{n+m}(x) = 0.$$

I wonder if it is possible to use the generating function identity:

$$ g(x,t) = \exp\left[\frac{x}{2}\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)\right]=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}J_n(x)\,t^n,$$

maybe through the substitution $t\to \frac{1}{t}$.

A little confused. Help appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Jacobi-Anger expansion:
$$e^{ix\cos\theta}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}i^n J_n(x)\, e^{i n\theta}\tag{1}$$
it follows that:
$$e^{i(x\cos\theta-m\theta)}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}i^n J_n(x) e^{i (n-m)\theta}=i^m\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}i^n J_{n+m}(x)e^{in\theta}$$
so, mapping $\theta$ into $\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta$ then into $-\theta$:
$$e^{ix\sin\theta} = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(-1)^n J_n(x)\, e^{-in\theta},\tag{2}$$
$$(-1)^m e^{i(x\sin\theta+m\theta)}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(-1)^n J_{n+m}(x)\,e^{-in\theta}$$
$$(-1)^m e^{-i(x\sin\theta+m\theta)}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}(-1)^n J_{n+m}(x)\,e^{in\theta}\tag{3}$$
and by the orthogonality relations for the complex exponential, provided that $m\neq 0$:
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}J_n(x)\,J_{n+m}(x)=\frac{(-1)^m}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{ix\sin\theta}e^{-i(x\sin\theta+m\theta)}\,d\theta = 0.\tag{4}$$

Comment: Thank you Jack D'Aurizio for answering it. I could not follow you when you go from (2) to the next step. Could you please explain in a little more details? Thank you once again.

Comment: @AnnieStein: I just replaced $\theta$ with $\pi/2-\theta$ in the formula that follows $(1)$, then replaced $\theta$ with $-\theta$.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to prove if we use t->t^-1 in the generating function? then use the orthogonality relations you showed?

Comment: @AnnieStein: yes, it is the same approach. In general, I prefer to use the harmonic analysis path, more than the generating function technique, but it is just a matter of taste.

Comment: thank you for answering so quickly.

Comment: @AnnieStein: you're welcome :)